# How do I match a colon with no values after it?

Tags: regex

I'm new to the website and to Regular Expression as well.
So I want to bookmark a list of Emails that have no value after the colons ":" as highlighted in the picture below.

[image: Link]

Here is an example:

```
abcdef@gmail.com:123456
abcdEF452@gmail.com:test123#@NEW
abcdef@gmail.com:
abcdef@gmail.com:
```

I only want to bookmark the last two ones so it would be like this:

```
abcdef@gmail.com:
abcdef@gmail.com:
```

Comment: Hint: `$` matches the end of the string. So match `:` followed by `$`.

Comment: Could you give us more examples? After the colons is there a space? Or a linebreak? Maybe there is always a number after the colon?

Comment: @robni

If the strings are like this:

abcd458EF@gmail.com:test123#@NEW
abcd@gmail.com:test123
abcd@gmail.com:TEST123
abcd@gmail.com:1234

then the bookmark should not work, it should work only when there is nothing after the colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex will match the "pre-colon" pattern if and only if it is followed by nothing but whitespace until the end of the line:

```
\w+@\w+\.\w+:\s*$
```

[View on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OMdm2O/3)

Note that matching email addresses with 100% correctness is [more complicated than this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), but this will likely do for your use case.

Comment: Above I only gave an example, so the value after colons could be letters, digits, symbols or all together. I would really appreciate if you can give me the proper one that matches only the Email Address followed with colons and when followed by anything after the colons it does not match them.

Comment: Still not useful 

Comment: @AINTHATOUGH What about now?

Comment: Actually I did some mistakes when I first created the topic but I have edited it now.

Comment: Nothing yet unfortunately.

Comment: @AINTHATOUGH Sorry, my mistake. I've fixed it now and added a regex101 link so you can see it working for yourself.

Comment: OMG, man you just made my day, I really appreciate that and wish you all the best!
It worked perfectly and exactly what I needed: https://i.vgy.me/Xdigrd.png

Thank you again!

Comment: How do I do that? sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and I still don't know how it works.

Comment: @AINTHATOUGH The checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: What if there is more than one period in the Email? For example: 123452yahoo.co.uk or 12345@yahoo.co.ne.jp

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to find strings that end with a colon, then all you need is `:$`.

Comment: "No value following" is not the same as "string ending with". You can see in the screenshot that there is trailing whitespace.

Comment: In fact, there might be a string like this one:

abcdef@gmail:123456:

Which means this one ":$" is not going to be helpful

Comment: `:$` will still match even if there are two colons.  And if you want to allow for whitespace then `:\s*$`.

Comment: "`:$` will still match even if there are two colons" - I believe that's the issue - the line is the pattern <email>:<value>, and that value can include and end with colons.

Comment: So the real requirement then is "only one colon, and it must be at the end of the string, although whitespace is OK."

Comment: It matched the last one as well!

Check: https://i.vgy.me/bvXOeQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+: # Only a-zA-Z, numbers are not accepted
```

Note: the last character is a space *" "*

```
[\w+]+@[\w+]+: # \w+ = Matches one or more [A-Za-z0-9_]
```

Without a space it will matches only these with no character after the colon.

```
[\w+]+@[\w+]+.*:$ # Matches only when there is also .XXX. For example: .com or .de
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't serve my need.

Comment: To be more clear, what I need to bookmark is any Email Address followed with colons and nothing after.

Comment: @AINTHATOUGH If you need nothing else after: Try it without a space.

Comment: The thing is that when there is another colon after the first one it gets matched as well and that's what I don't need. To summarise everything, the Regular Expression should match only if there is any Email Address followed with a colon and nothing after it but when the colon is followed with any value and another colon it should not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I find this request a bit odd, perhaps if you could elaborate a bit more on your use case I may be able to provide a better approach or solution.

Now, I think that this expression should work the way you expect:

```
[\w\.]+@[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]?
```

Add the colon sign at the end if you need to match for the colon sign as well.

I noticed that the other proposed expressions don't account for email addresses with a dot in the username part or with dashed in the domain part. You may use a combination of all the solutions if you are more familiar with RegEx. I highly recommend you test the expression before moving it to production, you can do further tests easily on this page https://regexr.com/.

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Will be a more adequate RegEx since the Internet Engineering Task Force established limits on how an email address can be formatted and this accounts for those additional characters. More details on this page https://www.mailboxvalidator.com/resources/articles/acceptable-email-address-syntax-rfc/.

As a friendly reminder, Stack Overflow can be best used when you have already invested some effort in fixing some problem, rather than having a community member provide you with a straight answer. This and other suggestions are listed on this other page https://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
abcdEF452@gmail.com:test123#@NEW
```

There are three parts to this:

1. Before the `@`.
2. Between the `@` and the `:`
3. After the `:`

If we assume (1) has to be there and not empty.
If we assume (2) has to be there and not empty.
If we assume (3) the ':' is required by the trailing part can be empty.
I don't want to make assumptions about other requirements.

Then I would use:

```
[^@]+@[^:]+:.*$
```

Meaning:

```
[^@]     => Anything apart from the '@' character.
[^@]+    => The above 1 or more times.
[^@]+@   => The above followed by '@' character.

[^:]     => Anything apart from the ':' character.
[^:]+    => The above 1 or more times.
[^:]+:   => The above followed by ':' character.

.*       => Any character 0 or more times.

$        end of line.
```

So if we want to mkae sure we only find things that don't have anything after the ':' we can simplify a bit.

```
    [^@]+@[^:]+:$
```

Make sure we have the '@' and ':' parts and they are none empty. But the colon is followed by the end of line.

If you don't care about part (1) or (2) we can simplify even more.

```
    [^:]+:$
```

Line must contain a `:` don't care what is in front as long as there is a least one character before the ':' and zero after.

Final simplification.

```
    :$
```

If you don't care about anything except that the colon is not followed by anything.